# SquareUp recurring payment on checkout

Tags: opencart, square, opencart-3, opencart-module

I have setup the squareup extension with recurring profiles. However, it seems the charge does not occur on the checkout, only the item charge. I did look at the extension code and it sets up the recurring payment however i see not evidence of a charge.

I am assuming this functionality is not there? If there is does anyone know how i could enable this?

If not how could i go about setting it up? I am thinking just take the charge code from the cron code and charge it at the checkout?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The charge can be only for the subscription, the product containing the subscription can be free or any amount which is charged one time.
After checkout using, for example paypal express, or any other method that supports subscriptions, opencart is out of the loop. Paypal will automatically charge the customer each cycle and report back to opencart, where you can view the transactions made.